# Highcharts - On Click event

Tags: highcharts

the question may be stupid, I apologize. I am looping through the different objects in a JSON with a $.each loop, and for each one I build a chart with Highcharts with the following code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: ('chart' + index),
                type: 'line',
                backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', // Transparent BG
                width:190,
                height: 80,
                events:{ 
                    click: function(e){
                        drawChart('area',index);
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    marker: { enabled: false }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: xAxis,
                labels: { enabled:false },
                lineWidth:0,
                tickWidth: 0,
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: { text: null }, // Set the text to null to disable the label
                labels: { enabled: false },
                gridLineWidth: 0
            },  
            series: [{
                data: yAxis,
                color: '#FFF'
            }]
        });
```

As you can see, I have specified a "click" event because I need to activate the click on the plotArea. The click should call another function that draws a chart in a specified , but it's not working :( Here's the drawChart() function.

```
function drawChart(ctype,index){

    var chartWidth = $("#container").width() - 50;
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: (ctype + 'Chart'),
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', // Transparent BG
            width: chartWidth,
            height:400,
            type: ctype
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: { enabled: false }
            },
            series: {
                shadow: { color: '#CCC' },
                stickyTracking: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: itemsX[index]
        },  
        series: [{
            data: itemsY[index],
            type: ctype,
            color: '#CCCCCC'
        }]
    });
} // Close drawChart()
```

Could somebody help me understanding why? Thanks!

Comment: any error messages printed to your console?

Comment: no error messages, I also tried to console.log the index var, thinking that maybe it was not passed correctly but it is...

Comment: will be good to have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: how is `drawChart` "not working"?

Comment: @Ishank, you're right, I will do it asap. CFS, it is not working in the sense that it is not drawing the chart. The function is called somewhere else in my code and it works, but if I call it from the click event spec in the Highcharts options it doesn't

Comment: Mmmmm, I tried building an easier example in jsFiddle and it works...http://jsfiddle.net/laurax1981/BGkTB/33/ So I am going to check for some error in my loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is about closures in javascript. You are using loop for creating charts so events are not properly binded, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

There is also possible solution, or try to use something like this:

```
$.each(array, function(index, element) { 
  (function(element) { //element or index
     var chart = ... //create chart 

  })(element)
});
```

Comment: i too thought the same, but `new` is been used in every iteration, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/8trK4/2/)

Comment: Remove `new` keyword and alert will work still fine. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8trK4/3/)

Comment: true, my function is behaving as a `closure`..that means the code in the `$.each` loop shall go in a closure even if it has a `new`..but the `$.each` is rendering the charts properly..its that the click function is not behaving as expected..

Comment: I guess so, because, even there is `new`, you are using some local variable to pass specific argument to `drawChart()` function.

Answer (score 1):

1. `renderTo: (ctype + 'Chart'),`  appears bad(Mostly, it shall be the `id` of the `<div>` container tag in the mark up).
2. Are you sure that `itemsX[index]` and `itemsY[index]` are arrays and are non empty?
3. Wat is the use of giving `type: ctype,` in `series: [{data: itemsY[index],type: ctype,color: '#CCCCCC'}]`?

**EDIT:** may see this- [replica](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/BGkTB/37/) as per my understanding

Comment: Hi Ishank
1 - (ctype + 'Chart') returns the ID of the chart container, ctype is a variable holding the type of the chart ('area','line',...) so that I can use one function to draw many charts.
2 - Yes, I console.logged them and they are not empty at all
3 - Mmmm, doesn't add anything actually...

Comment: so, some already existing html `<div>` tag has the id by value `ctype + 'Chart'` ?

Comment: Aye, ctype is basically the type of chart, and I have <div id="areaChart"> and <div id="lineChart"> in my HTML

Comment: and, did u check the `(ctype + 'Chart')` in `drawChart` using Console?